# What is the syntax for an Anonymous type in VB?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, anonymous-types

i am trying to set the htmlAttribute property but i cant figure out the correct syntax

here is how it works in c#

```
<%=Html.Password("myPassword", 50,"",new { style = "width:100px" })%><br />
```

what would be the vb.net version of

```
new { style = "width:100px" }
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax for an inline anonymous type in VB is:

```
New With { .Style = "width:100px" }
```

If you want to declare an anonymous type use this syntax:

```
Dim myVariable = New With { .Style = "width:100px" }
```